# Open url from PHP link iphone

Tags: php, iphone, uibutton

Hey all, I have a phpmyadmin site, that I use for my databasing/updating my iphone app

I am looking to do the following:

- when a user clicks a UIButton
- this button will grab a url from a php file (on my server) and inside that php file it will grab a URL from one of my tables, and continue to open safari to that URL

I have been trying to do this for hours, but with little experience with the iOS dev kit,  I am still learning :-)

converting the text in my php file from text to open a URL in the iOS safari with that url posted inside my php file....

here is what I have done
- my h file is setup with the `-(IBAction)linkbutton;`

my .m file has.....

```
   -(IBAction)LinkButton{
    NSURL *linkurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/link.php"];
    NSString *linkresponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:linkurl];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkurl];
```

however, i know I have to use `linkresponse` rather then `linkurl`, since it is converted that php file which is another URL (ie, youtube video or other link), however with `linkresponse` it does CRASH, and with `linkurl` it opens my PHP file in safari, with the appropriate link displaying on the page, as my PHP file is setup correctly....

any help would be great

Comment: Can you give me an example of the link.pnp you are working with? That way I can help you parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the contents of a URL, you should read Apple's [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html). `-[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:]` *does* do what its name implies: it initializes with the contents of a URL. However, that method is mainly (supposed to be) used to load the contents of local files with URLs like `http://localhost/...`. For this, you should use URL fetching instead.

Does that make sense?